# DRF and django_filters. Change queryset before applying filters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

There is a ModelViewSet and a FilterSet that work great. But the problem is that I need to transform the queryset before filtering, for this I overridden the get_queryset() method. It changes the queryset, but as a result, on the page with a list of objects, I see that no changes have occurred.

If I override the list() method using the rewritten get_queryset() method in it:

```
queryset = self.get_queryset()
```

Changes will occur, but filters will not work on this queryset. I tried using:

```
qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

in this case, the filters work, but the data on the page remains as it was before the change in get_queryset(). Please tell me what is my mistake, why can't I filter the queryset with changes and what should be done to make the filtering of the transformed queryset possible?

**EDIT:**

views.py

```
from .serializers import OfferSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .models import Offer


def validate(price:str, term:str, deposit:str) -> bool:
    """ Validating type of parameters. """
    try:
        price, term, deposit = int(price), int(term), int(deposit)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def calculate_payment(qs, price:str, term:str, deposit:str):
    """ Calculating payment by entry parameters and bank rate. """
    clear_payment = (int(price) - int(deposit)) / (int(term) * 12)
    for el in qs:
        rate_multiplier = (el.rate + 100) / 100
        el.payment = clear_payment * rate_multiplier
    

class OfferFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    payment_min = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="payment", lookup_expr='gte')
    payment_max = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="payment", lookup_expr='lte')
    rate_min = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="rate", lookup_expr='gte')
    rate_max = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="rate", lookup_expr='lte')
    bank_name = filters.CharFilter(field_name="bank_name", lookup_expr='contains')

    order_by = filters.OrderingFilter(
        fields=(
            ('payment', 'payment'),
            ('bank_name', 'bank_name'),
            ('rate', 'rate'),
        ),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('payment_min', 'payment_max', 'rate_min', 'rate_max', 'bank_name')
    

class OfferViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = OfferFilter
    filterset_fields = ['rate', 'payment', 'bank_name']

    def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = Offer.objects.all()
            query_params = dict(self.request.GET.items())
            if 'price' in query_params and 'term' in query_params:
                deposit = query_params['deposit'] if 'deposit' in query_params else 0
                price = query_params['price']
                term = query_params['term']
                if validate(price, term, deposit):
                    calculate_payment(queryset, price, term, deposit)
            return queryset

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
            queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
        return queryset

    def list (self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = OfferSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the ModelViewSet and FilterSet?

Comment: Please check, I have edited the question.

Comment: You call a function `calculate_payment` that iterates over the queryset and sets some attributes on the results and you are wondering why those attributes don't appear in the results after the queryset is then filtered?

Comment: You mean that calculate_payment must return queryset, not just change it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset instead of iterating over it and setting attributes

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

...

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Offer.objects.all()
        query_params = dict(self.request.GET.items())
        if 'price' in query_params and 'term' in query_params:
            deposit = query_params['deposit'] if 'deposit' in query_params else 0
            price = query_params['price']
            term = query_params['term']
            if validate(price, term, deposit):
                clear_payment = (int(price) - int(deposit)) / (int(term) * 12)
                queryset = queryset.annotate(
                    rate_multiplier=(F('rate') + Value(100.0)) / Value(100.0)
                ).annotate(
                    payment=Value('clear_payment') * F('rate_multiplier')
                )
            return queryset
```

If Django cannot work out the correct return type from the annotations you may need to wrap them in [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) to specify the return type

Comment: I have tried it earlier but got this:

ValueError at /api/offer/
The annotation 'payment' conflicts with a field on the model.

I think it's because annotate with this name is already exist. Of course I can set another name, but I need to change the 'payment' field

Comment: @marquensis_13 is your intention to save the calculation to the DB or just calculate a new display value for it?

Comment: Just calculate new display value

Comment: @marquensis_13 could you just give the annotation a different name and use that in your serializer/filter? You seem to also then filter on this new value in the FilterSet?

Comment: The queryset does not always change, but only when there are additional input parameters. I have already written a serializer and a filterset for default(not changed) fields, do I need to write new ones to apply them when the queryset does change?